# Unable to retrieve Header information on Orbeon 4.0.1 but works on 3.9

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to get header information using the function : get-request-header().

It works on Orbeon 3.9 :

```
<xforms:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" nodeset="control-1" 
 type="xforms:string" xxforms:default="xxforms:get-request-header('User-Agent')"/>
</xforms:bind>
```

But nothing is returned on Orbeon 4.0.1, field is empty :

```
<xf:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" ref="control-1"
    xxf:default="xxf:get-request-header('User-Agent')"/>
```

I also tested in the demo environment (http://demo.orbeon.com/orbeon/home/) and still nothing. Unable to retrieve header information in a form.

The function get-request-header() doesn't work on Orbeon 4.0.1.

Regards,
Sefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like 4.0 requires the header name to be lower case, which looks like an unindented regression. So for now, as a workaround, use instead `xxforms:get-request-header('user-agent')`. And once [this issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/926) is fixed, you'll be able to use mixed case header names again.

Comment: Thank you, it works!

I did this test to find the error to my initial problem. Currently, I'm trying to integrate in Liferay one Orbeon form which retrieves the user name. But it still doesn't work even in lowercase.
I will open a new thread for this.