# Unable to retrieve liferay user name in Orbeon proxy portlet

Tags: orbeon

Currently, I'm trying to integrate in Liferay one Orbeon form which retrieves the user name.
(I described the problem here: http://discuss.orbeon.com/Unable-to-retrieve-liferay-roles-in-Orbeon-proxy-portlet-td4656273.html - Post 2 )

To do this, I created a simple form with one input field and I want to get the Liferay user name in this field. I tested with all configurations in lower case ([Unable to retrieve Header information on Orbeon 4.0.1 but works on 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953620/unable-to-retrieve-header-information-on-orbeon-4-0-1-but-works-on-3-9)) and nothing is returned.

First: I completed properties-local.xml using http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/deployment-portlet and I put all properties in lower case.

properties-local.xml :

```
  <!-- this is the property for orbeon forms 4.0 -->
    <property as="xs:anyuri"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.exist-uri"
              value="http://orbeonserver:8080/orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr"/>

   <!-- configure authentication properties through headers -->
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.method"
              value="header"/>

    <!-- if you want the liferay user email used for form runner authentication -->
    <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.authentication.header.username"
              value="orbeon-liferay-user-email"/>

    <!-- if you want liferay roles used -->
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.header.roles"
              value="orbeon-liferay-user-roles"/>

    <!-- to propagate username/roles to the persistence layer, if using authentication -->
    <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.forward-submission-headers"
              value="orbeon-username orbeon-roles"/>
```

After in my form, I used xxf:get-request-header() to get the Liferay user name :

```
<xf:bind id="userName-bind" name="userName" ref="userName"
         xxf:default="xxf:get-request-header('orbeon-liferay-user-email')"/>
```

Finally to insert the form in Liferay, I used the orbeon proxy-portlet.war (no configuration in this side).

I see the form but field is still empty. Nothing is returned. I missed a step ?

FYI, I used: liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2 and orbeon-4.0.1.201303152357-PE (free trial license). Orbeon and Liferay are on 2 different server.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a very recent version of Orbeon proxy portlet (4.1-ce from github), since the following issue got closed only a month ago:
https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/886 "Proxy portlet: ability to configure forwarding of headers and parameters". Accordingly, the 4.01 version of Orbeon proxy portlet lacks this ability.

Comment: I tested Orbeon Forms 4.1.0.M1.201303290130 with own proxy-portlet and I got the same result. 

I configured Liferay to use Charles as a proxy. I wanted more information between Liferay and Orbeon.
And when I checked HTTP headers in Charles, there was only one Orbeon specific variable : 'Orbeon-Client' (never orbeon-liferay-user-email or orbeon-liferay-user-roles).